# Assign refs to child components using VueRouter - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, reference, vue-router

I have the following code in my `main.js` file in my Vue webapp:

```
const routes = {
  name: "Main",
  path: "/main",
  redirect: "/main/home",
  component: MainComponent,
  children: [
    { path: "home", name: "Main_Home", component: MainHomeComponent },
    { path: "play", name: "Main_Play", component: PlayComponent },
  ]
}
    
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
});
```

Currently, the routing and component rendering is working really well, however from my `MainComponent`, I want to trigger a method within a child component. I understand that I can do that with `refs` in Vue, however I'm not sure how I can create them with `VueRouter`, as the components are being loaded by `VueRouter`. Here is my `MainComponent.js`:

```
<template>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Main Component</h1>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A template ref on the `router-view` will automatically apply to the view's rendered component. With that template ref, you could access the child's method directly:

```html
<template>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Main Component</h1>
    <button @click="callChildMethod">Call child method</button>
    <router-view ref="view"></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    callChildMethod() {
      this.$refs.view.myMethod()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/calling-child-views-method-through-refs-ksgdp?file=/src/components/MainComponent.vue)